# Counting boolean values under rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a standard master-detail relationship between two models in a RoR application. The detail records contain four boolean fields indicating presence / absence of something.

When I display the detail records I want to add a summary indicating the number of records which have their boolean value set to True for each of the four boolean fields.

For example:
Date       | Boolean Field 1 | Boolean Field 2 | etc
2009/08/29 |        T        |        T        |
2009/08/30 |        T        |        F        |
2009/08/31 |        F        |        T        |
2009/09/01 |        F        |        T        |

Total: 4            2                 3

I tried using something like @entries.count(["Boolean Field 1", true])
The way I see it, there are two ways to calculate these values: one at the model by executing an SQL query (ugly) or at the view level by using a counter (ugly again.) Is there some other way to achieve what I want?

Thank you for your time,

Angelos Arampatzis

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May be

```
@entries.select {|r| r.bool_field1}.size
```

Comment: `@entries.select(&:bool_field1).size` rather

Answer (score 4):

You can either do:

```
@entries.count(:conditions => { :boolean_field_1 => true })
```

You can pretty this up by doing a named scope:

```
named_scope :booleans,  :conditions => { :boolean_field_1 => true })
```

and then

```
@entries.booleans.count
```

Or if you already have ALL the items in an array (rather than a select few) and do not want to hit the database…

Rails provides a ? method for all columns. So while you have:

```
@entry.boolean_field
```

You also have:

```
@entry.boolean_field?
```

So you can do this:

```
@entries.collect(&:boolean_field?).length
```

Answer (score 1):

sql isn't as ugly as rails makes it out to be and it is rather efficient, just make it a named_scope and your controller/view will still look pretty

Answer (score 0):

Because you have all your entries as Rails objects, you can use the shortest form:

```
@entries.count(&:boolean_field1?)
```

It's using `Enumerable#count`.

Keep in mind though, that it counts using Ruby (as opposed to SQL). If you'll ever want to count without reading all records from DB, you will need to use something different for efficiency.